Why can I not reply to posts using Praw?
Going to preface this by saying that I am very new to coding and I literally started using praw like 2 days ago so please forgive me in advance.
I am currently trying to build a bot that responds to posts on r/learnpython that ask for basic python projects. The bot should then grabs the links of other posts with similar keywords and responds to the original post with those links. Can someone please show me where I went wrong with my code because it has been throwing errors left and right.
My Code:
import praw
#BUILDING A BOT
for submission in reddit.subreddit('learnpython').search('easy coding projects'):
links = submission.url
for submission in reddit.subreddit('learnpython').search('easy coding projects'):
submission.reply(links)
